# redirect django runserver output in order to debug with pudb

Tags: django, tty, pudb

I'm currently trying to use `pudb` to troubleshoot a django application.
In order to do so, I'm running the `runserver` instead of `gunicorn`.

Then, when I want to debug, I added:

```
import pudb; pu.db
```

The pudb gui shows up correctly but is quickly garbled by the runserver output.

As per [`pudb` documentation](https://documen.tician.de/pudb/starting.html#debugging-from-a-separate-terminal), I can avoid this by setting the `PUDB_TTY` variable before starting the server.

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/3
$ PUDB_TTY=/dev/pts/3 manage.py ... runserver ...
```

Unfortunately, the GUI still gets garbled by the output of the server.

Alternatively, I tried to redirect all output from the runserver (`>/dev/null 2>&1`), but the `pudb` output also get caught (obviously).

Is there a way to:

- have the runserver not produce any output?
- tweak `pudb` ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the TTY redirect feature is only available in the Development branch

I was able to get it to work with:

```
$> git clone https://github.com/inducer/pudb
$> cd pudb
$> python setup.py install
```

In terminal 1:

```
$> tty 
   # Outputs: /dev/pts/5
$> perl -MPOSIX -e pause
```

In terminal 2:

```
$> PUDB_TTY=/dev/pts5 python manage.py runserver
```